# Cast webpage by url via Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I want to cast web page programmatically (not from chrome). Is there a way, for example, pass a url so chromecast can render it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to cast URL. As a beginner, I would refer to "[Get Started](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers)" official Chromecast document to get grip on Chromecast development.

1. Android Sender => To develop an Android sender app
2. iOS Sender => To develop an iOS sender app
3. Chrome Sender => To develop an chrome sender app
4. CAF Receiver => To develop a receiver app

If you have already referred to above document and looking for something else. I would recommend you to update your question with more details like why you are unable to achieve your goal and what steps did you try to achieve your goal, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I read the docs, did some research and found that my problem will be solved by writing custom sender with its custom receiver. Also, I wrote a kind of a boilerplate of custom sender and receiver. Here it is.


[https://github.com/Spardevil/chromecast-sender-receiver](https://github.com/Spardevil/chromecast-sender-receiver)